# how to clear cache on iphone 6 so it reloads the css file

Tags: css, iphone, caching

I have my iphone plugged into my mac laptop.  When I visit my site on the desktop everything loads correctly.  For some reason when I make changes to my css script file it will not update on the iphone. I've cleared cache, used private browsing but it's a real problem.  Does anyone know how to force the iphone to reload the css file?  Please no guessing.

Comment: Why don't u give version to your css js files?

Comment: You can try adding a random parameter `file.css?test=something`

Comment: @zohir salak, thanks that works!  It amazes me how many swear by apple when their products are such crap

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this? 
Settings => Safari => Clear History and Website Data

Comment: 3,757 times.  Apple products really suck

Comment: @DCR, maybe this was helpful for you: [css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/ios-safari-caching-problems-how-to-get-ios-safari-to-behave-a-bit-better/)